# XMLHttpRequest onload property?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I like to do as much code as possible without jquery, so for ajax requests, I've been doing something along the lines of what the MDN said:

```
function alertContents(httpRequest) {  
  try {  
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {  
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {  
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);  
      } else {  
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');  
      }  
    }  
  }  
  catch( e ) {  
    alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);  
  }  
}
```

I was looking at the Google tutorial for making extensions and they used the onload of their request. Is the onload an event listening that runs when the readystate is 4 and the status 200? If not, what is it, and when do I use it instead of the above method.

Comment: why not implement it and see when it fires?  I'm going to give it a shot

Comment: Many "ajax wrappers" call a success on `readyState === 4`.  Give this page a shot, it shows a nice example of a `AJAX` wrapper that includes an `onSuccess` method: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-ajaxhistory/index.html

Answer (score 2):

XHR level 2 with cross origin implements other events than onreadystatechange, which are progress events (specify the statechange); loadstart, progress, error, abort, load, loadend

you may use the onload event as pre-checked readystate 4, and go on to check the XHR status (200 -> 300 || 304 i'd imagine)

Comment: The OP said `onload`, you refer to `load`, which one is it?

Comment: "load" is the event name, the property that listens to it is "onload".
Think: request.onload = function... and request.addListener("load", function...)