# Shortcut for XMLHttpRequest passed response (4)?

Tags: javascript

Looking for `readyState === 4` and `status === 200` is so common, I believe there was a shortcut developed for it, but I can't remember it.

It was a language shorcute, i.e., you don't need a library.

```
if (this.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

What is the "shortcut" to check for this "situation"?

Comment: There are lots and lots of lightweight JavaScript libraries which abstract this process.

Comment: there's no shortcut unless you encapsulate it yourself, or use the `load` event instead of the `onreadystatechange` event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870704/xmlhttprequest-onload-property?rq=1

Comment: @Bill-TheButcher-Cutting yes, I think that's what I said too (or not? sometimes my english confuses me)

Comment: just providing a link for those who wish to look into it more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a shortcut outside of a library. Use one if statement.

```
if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
  config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Note: **You cannot switch the order of the if statement**, because you can't get the status of the request until the readyState gets to at least 2.  So if you put the status check first, your browser will throw an error on the first readyState, which is 0.

source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `onload` event listener (instead of `onreadystatechange`, you can simply do:

```
if (this.status === 200) {
  config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
}
```

as onload only fires when `readyState === 4`.